# Find objects created in last week in mongo

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection which has a field called `timestamp` containing date object. I have this query:

```
db.articles.find({
    timestamp:{
       '$lte':new Date(),
       '$gte': //Something to get the last week's date
    }
})
```

Also if it is possible, Can I sort these returned documents by length of an array in this document. Here is the schema:

```
section: String,
title: String,
abstract: String,
url: String,
image: {
    url: String,
    caption: String
},
votes:{
    up: [ObjectID],
    down: [ObjectID]
},
comments:[ObjectID],
timestamp: Date
```

I want to sort the returned objects by size of difference of `votes.up` and `votes.down`. Right now I am sorting the returned objects in Javascript where this actually returns the data.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Seems the solution should look like

```
db.articles.find({
    timestamp: {
        $gte: new Date(new Date() - 7 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000)
    }
});
```

Comment: can you please explain, 7 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000

Comment: @RahulBera, last week means 7 days * 24 hours per day * 60 minutes per hour * 60 seconds per minute * 1000 milliseconds per second.

Comment: You could use `Date.now() - 7 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000` as well.

Answer (score 3):

it will return the previous week data i.e.,from sunday to saturday of previous week which is local where sunday is a starting day.

```
        { 
          $match: {
            createdAt: { 
              $gte: moment().day(-7).toDate(),
               $lt: moment().startOf('week').toDate()
            },
          }
        }
      ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution get the objects created in last week.

```
db.articles.find({timestamp:{'$lte':new Date(),'$gte':new Date(Date()-7)}})
```

This gets the work done. But I cant figure out how to sort the returned objects by the size of arrays.

Comment: `Date() - 7` returns `NaN`

Comment: It might just be a typo in the answer. You'd have to use `new Date() - 7` to fix the command. That said, I'm not sure which time part the 7 is referring to here.